# What is the unit of the output of df -k?

Tags: linux, shell

What is the unit for `Used` and `Available`? And what does `1K-blocks` mean? Does it mean that the size is in kB?

Command:

`df -k | head -2`

Output:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7              9920592   1054440   8354084  12% /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df):

> Display values are in units of the first available SIZE from **--block-size**, and the DF_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCKSIZE environment variables. Otherwise, units default to 1024 bytes (or 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set).
>
> SIZE may be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one of following: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on for G, T, P, E, Z, Y.

The `-k` switch is equal to `--block-size=1K`, which means that the numbers are in multiples of 1024 bytes.

Comment: Two environment variables also affect this, along with find, du, df, ls and others...  BLOCKSIZE=1K sets the default as if you used the '-k' or '--block-size=1K' options, while the BLOCK_SIZE (note the underscore) does the same, but has some other options available.  I set my BLOCK_SIZE to \'1 (backslash,single-quote,one) which causes find,du,df,ls (and others) to display using COMMAS!!!  So much easier to parse!

Comment: So does it mean `9920592 kB`, `1054440 kB`?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Yes. You can check by dividing the numbers by 1048576 (1024*1024) and seeing if they match the output of `df -h`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right, as the doc says:

```
 -k      Use 1024-byte (1-Kbyte) blocks, rather than the default.  Note
         that this overrides the BLOCKSIZE specification from the environ-
         ment.
```

Comment: **Question**: "What is the unit?"  **Your answer**: "Yes".  Huh???

Comment: To that he guessed.

Comment: @sawdust I guess the Yes is clearly answering to "Does it mean that the size is in kB?"